# Probability that all the cards are of distinct rank

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, card-games

Five cards are selected randomly from a standard deck of $52$ cards. Find the probability that all of them are of different rank.

My try:

The first card can be picked in $52$ ways. Now ignore the other three cards of this rank. Now pick second card which can be done in $48$ ways. Third in $44$ ways. Fourth in $40$ ways and fifth in $36$ ways. Since the order of selection is not important, the total ways is:
$$\frac{52 \times 48 \times 44 \times 40 \times 36}{5 !}$$

The required Probability is:
$$p=\frac{\left(\frac{52 \times 48 \times 44 \times 40 \times 36}{5 !}\right)}{\binom{52}{5}}=\frac{2112}{4165}$$

Is this correct way?

Comment: Yes, this appears to be correct. As a variant, note that the first choice can be anything.  The second can be any of $48$ from $51$ and so on.  Thus the answer is $\frac {52}{52}\times \frac {48}{51}\times\cdots \times  \frac {36}{48}$ which matches your result.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, that is correct.

The probability for obtaining *five from thirteen* ranks with each of *one from four* suits, when selecting *five from fifty two* cards is:$$\dfrac{\dbinom{13}5\dbinom{4}1^5}{\dbinom{52}{5}}=\dfrac{(13\cdot 4)(12\cdot 4)(11\cdot 4)(10\cdot 4)(9\cdot 4)}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot 49\cdot 48}$$